# How to get current (foreground) activity name?

Tags: applications, automation, logging

Hoi! I'm trying to make an automatic night mode for my phone using "Automate", but I can't find certain app activities. How do I get to know what activities are executed in the foreground at the moment, so I can start it?

Comment: Legit question, but you probably want to edit to make sure it doesn't appear off-topic. (lemme do that for you this time, hope I understood it right) // Unrelated: that "hoi" sounds a lot like Temmie.

Comment: Forgot to add: feel free to edit on top or even perform a rollback if I put it wrong - it's your post after all.

Answer (score 10):

Using apps: [Current Activity](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.willme.topactivity) and some similar apps will display the info in the form of floating texts above the screen content.

Using `adb` (from your PC): `dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'`, or `dumpsys activity top` (for full info meant for developers)

Comment: Note: it's `adb shell ...`

Answer (score 3):

To add to @AndyYan's answer, you can also use a terminal emulator app, if you don't have a computer but have root privileges. In this case, execute `su` first. Then, to dump the focused activity, the command is

```
dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedActivity
```

The command, if e.g. executed from [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm), gives the following output:

```
  mFocusedActivity: ActivityRecord{415c7ae u0 jackpal.androidterm/.Term t96}
```

---

The command above, as Andy pointed out, merely shows the Terminal's own activity, though. In order to give yourself enough time to open the app you wish to investigate, though, you need to prepend

```
sleep <seconds> &&
```

before the actual `dumpsys`command, replacing `<seconds>` with the number of seconds you want the shell to wait. An example of complete command, thus, will resemble

```
sleep 10 && dumpsys activity activities | grep mFocusedActivity
```

After executing the command, open the app you wish to investigate, and keep it in foreground for the number of seconds you specified. Once the time has elapsed, the shell will report the activity's name.

---

*I'm not affiliated to the abovementioned app.*

Comment: @AndyYan Who said they can't? It's just a matter of adding `sleep x && ` before `dumpsys` (x must be replaced by how many seconds the terminal may wait), so that one can open the app they need to investigate, and let the terminal handle the rest. I'll add this to the answer later.

Comment: (facepalm) Obviously I'm no terminal guru...

Comment: @AndyYan Me neither. iBug's the one.